# Has anyone successfully built libjpeg with recent versions of CodeGear/Embarcadero RAD Studio?

Tags: c++builder, libjpeg

It apparently used to compile with Borland's C++ Builder, but that was a long time ago. Now I need to get it compiling with bcc32 for use in a bit of code that was /intended/ to be cross-compiler.

Anyone done it already and want to give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply modifying the makefile in makefile.bcc appears to be sufficient.

- remove the os2/dos check (# Are we under DOS or OS/2?)
- set the compiler name to bcc32 instead of bcc

Answer (score 0):

At least the current version (9c) supports C++ Builder out of the box (tested with 10.1).

1. Navigate to the source directory
2. Copy jconfig.bcc under name jconfig.h
3. With C++ Builder 10.3 you need an additional step, because libraries compiled with bcc32 cannot be used with bcc32c projects: Edit `makefile.b32` and change the compiler name to `bcc32c`.
4. Execute `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\
   18.0\bin\make" -f makefile.b32` (replace the path with path to C++ Builder install directory)

Files you need for your project:

- libjpeg.lib
- All header files